# How do I pull in a private username and password via Maven for testing?

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

In order to connect to an external system, for which each developer has a personal username and password, I need to pull in a username and password to my JUnit test cases:

```
String username = System.getProperty("ext.username");
```

The above line would be called inside any class inside my `test` folder

How can I best do this via Maven?  I think the best scope for the property is inside `settings.xml`, but I'm not sure about the best way to transfer it from there into my code.

Comment: Maybe just use `-D` options on the command line; allows more flexibility.

Comment: @Dave I'm running tests inside an IDE, so I'd prefer not to do that.  Flexibility is not ultimately important.

Comment: I don't really see the difference, since you can specify options in a run configuration, but okay. Obviously flexibility *is* important, or you wouldn't be asking. Why are you getting it from a system property anyway instead of a config file? Seems backwards to say "I want to define it as a system property but define it in a file."

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not exactly sure on the difference, unless you are just referring to my access mechanism.  I don't care about that, really -- I just want an easy way to get it (`System.getProperty` fits that req) and an easy way to define it per user in a non-VC location (`Settings.xml` makes sense).  What I meant is that flexibility is not important beyond that.  I don't personally like requiring any customization to persist inside my IDE.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is best solved using a Maven build profile.

In your POM you declare a default value for the properties (To prevent run-time possible errors).

```
<project>
..
    <properties>
        <ext.username>XXXXX</ext.username>
        <ext.password>YYYYY</ext.password>
    </properties>
```

Each developer can then override these properies in theor local build using a default profile specified in their settings file: *$HOME/.m2/settings.xml*

```
<settings>
    ..
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</dev>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <properties>
                <ext.username>XXXXX</ext.username>
                <ext.password>YYYYY</ext.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        ..
    </profiles>
    ..
</settings>
```

For those worried about security is also possible to [encrypt the password](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Finally, it's possible to have multiple profiles configured. These can be chosen at run-time (using profile id) in order to support multiple build environments:

```
mvn -Pdev  ..
mvn -Pprod ..
```